# Git push to Fortrabbit fails: No space left on device

Tags: git, fortrabbit

When trying to deploy to Fortrabbit today from my local machine, I received a strange error stating there's `No space left on device`. Is this a Fortrabbit problem or a local problem? There is plenty of space on the server as I just create the app. I was able to push fine just a few minutes before.

```
Pushing to #####@deploy.us1.frbit.com:#####.git
remote: error: unable to create temporary file: No space left on device        

remote: fatal: failed to write object        
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit

Commit received, starting build of branch master

–––––––––––––––––––––––  ∙ƒ  –––––––––––––––––––––––

...


A B O R T E D

!! Failure in packaging release 84ffaf590bef534f8740cdbf36095cfeeb9f3797. 
Please try again later.

To #####@deploy.us1.frbit.com:#####.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to '#####@deploy.us1.frbit.com:tgs-trial.git'
```

Comment: The word `remote` in the message `remote: error: unable to create temporary file: No space left on device` suggests that it's the issue on the hosting side. I'd recommend opening a ticket with them, or periodically retry `git push` a few more times.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Yes, it's fixed now, so that was the issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Yes, confirmed: There was an [incident yesterday](http://status.fortrabbit.com/incidents/9x0sm29h4kfd). 
(I am fortrabbit co-founder)

Answer (score 1):

Igor's comment is correct: The issue was on the remote and it's resolved now. If you run into this issue, I'd suggest waiting a bit for your host to resolve it.